# Python // Mechanize // Can't find form

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanize

I am using **Mechanize** to find and submit a form. The code is shown below:

```
url = "THIS_IS_A_LINK"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders=[('User-agent','chrome')]
br.open(url)
htmltext = br.open(url).read()
print htmltext

br.select_form(name="genericsearch_param.fulltext")
br["q"] = "metal"
res = br.submit()
content = res.read()
with open("mechanize_results.html", "w") as f:
   f.write(content)
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form method="get" action="/WHAT_SO_EVER" accept-charset="utf-8" class="clearfix" style="display: inline;"><input type="hidden" name="session.sessionid" value="sdfosdfosdf3482374892hsdfanw9023qjh"><input type="hidden" name="global_data.designmode" value="xf"><div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="left"><label for="genericsearch_param.fulltext">Searchterm</label><input type="text" class="text" id="genericsearch_param.fulltext" name="genericsearch_param.fulltext" value=""></div> <div class="right"><label for="genericsearch_param.part_id">Searcharea</label><select id="genericsearch_param.part_id" name="genericsearch_param.part_id">
```

I do not want to work with **Selenium** as it would have to much of the browser opening and closing. Why does **Mechanize** not find the form?

Answer (score -1):

Just select the first form on the p

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

and you sure submit button is working ?:

`submit_response = br.submit(name='action')` or `submit_response = br.submit(label='action')`

it's probably confusing which form you're trying to select.

Comment: awesome, glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much. Yes the above is correct for sites with only one form on it. Then, of course, the first is also the only one. To find the form I used

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
   for f in br.forms():
print f
```

Brought me the label. Again try and learn experience great on stackoverflow!